# USB Headset works with pulseaudio run in terminal but not as a service

Tags: sound, xubuntu, pulseaudio, 22.04, headset

I have a MPOW USB Headset which works (both speakers and microphone) when starting Terminal and entering:

```shell
pulseaudio -k
pulseaudio
```

However, when I start `pulseaudio` like this it doesn't work:

```shell
systemctl --user start pulseaudio.socket
systemctl --user start pulseaudio.service
```

When running just `pulseaudio` however I have to keep the Terminal window open. As soon as I stop `pulseaudio`, sound is gone again (which makes sense).

How can I run `pulseaudio` in the background and still have sound and microphone working?

Comment: the "brute-force answer" would be that `pulseaudio --daemonize` will run pulseaudio in the background. But the real issue is probably that there is some broken config that only gets run when pulseaudio is started as a service and not manually, and that's what needs to be fixed

Comment: @Esther `pulseaudio --daemonize` seems to work. However, how do I automate this on login/startup?

Comment: you don't, you figure out what's wrong with the configs. Try running with specifying no configs/each config file you have on your system, and see if one config file isn't working. [here](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man5/pulse-daemon.conf.5.html) are the manpages for pulseaudio, they list where configs might be found and how to run with no config file/specific config files

Comment: @Esther Thanks, will try to figure it out.

Comment: Looks like just restarting the PC fixed everything (attached the Headset for the first time yesterday).